# Frege: can I derive "Show" for a recursive type?

Tags: frege

I'm trying to implement the classical tree structure in frege, which works nicely as long as I don't use "derive":

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Empty
derive Show Tree
```

gives me

```
realworld/chapter3/E_Recursive_Types.fr:7: kind error, 
type constructor `Tree` has kind *->*, expected was *
```

Is this not supported or do I have to declare it differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the world of type kinds!

You must give the full type of the items you want to show. `Tree` is not a type (kind `*`), but something that needs a type parameter to become one (kind `* -> *`).

Try

```
derive Show (Tree a)
```

Note that this is shorthand for

```
derive Show (Show a => Tree a)
```

which resembles the fact that, to show a tree, you need to also know how to show the values in the tree (at least, the code generated by derive will need to know this - of course, one could write an instance manually that prints just the shape of the tree and so would not need it).

Generally, the kind needed in instances for every type class is fixed. The error message tells you that you need kind `*` for `Show`.

---

EDIT: eliminate another possible misconception

Note that this has nothing to do with your type being recursive. Let's take, for example, the definition of optional values:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

This type is not recursive, and yet we still cannot say:

```
derive Show Maybe   -- same kind error as above!!
```

But, given the following type class:

```
class ListSource c    -- things we can make a list from
    toList :: c a -> [a]
```

we **need** say:

```
instance ListSource Maybe where
    toList (Just x) = [x]
    toList Nothing  = []
```

(`instance`and `derive` are equivalent for the sake of this discussion, both make instances, the difference being that `derive` generates the instance functions automatically for certain type classes.)

It is, admittedly, not obvious why it is this way in one case and differntly in the other. The key is, in every case the type of the class operation we want to use. For example, in class `Show` we have:

```
class Show s where
    show :: s -> String
```

Now, we see that the so called class type variable `s` (which represents any future instantiated type expression) appears on its own on the left of the function array. This, of course, indicates that `s` must be a plain type (kind `*`), because we pass a value to `show` and every value has per definition a type of kind `*`. We can have values of types `Int` or `Maybe Int` or `Tree String`, but no value ever has a type `Maybe` or `Tree`.

On the other hand, in the definition of `ListSource`, the class type variable `c` is applied to some other type variable `a` in the type of `toList`, which also appears as list element type. From the latter, we can conclude, that `a` has kind `*` (because list elements are values). We know, that the type to the left and to the right of a function arrow must have kind `*` also, since functions take and return values. Therefore, `c a`  has kind `*`. Thus, `c` alone is something that, when applied to a type of kind `*` yields a type of kind `*`. This is written `* -> *`.

This means, in plain english, when we want to make an instance for `ListSource` we need the type constructor of some "container" type that is parameterized with another type. `Tree` and `Maybe` would be possible here, but not `Int`.

Comment: Now, that makes a lot of sense and is possibly one of the points where Frege is even more strict about its types than Haskell. Thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Comment: I linked https://github.com/Frege/frege/wiki/Differences-between-Frege-and-Haskell to here. Please correct my wording where need be.

Comment: @Dierk, (un)fortunately, GHC-Haskell is, as always, more advanced also in this respect. What Frege offers in the support of higher kinded types matches approximately Haskell 2010. Note also that this all has nothing to do with the type being recursive, rather the point is that you yourself said in your declaration that `Tree a` shall be a type. Hence, `Tree` alone can't be one, it is only a type constructor. Think of partially applied functions on the type level.

Comment: I suspected that the issue was more general than for my recursive example, but I'm plainly not versed enough to come up with the correct wording. What should I replace "recursive" with? Does this apply to all "parameterized types" (my current guess)? Or is there anything like a "kinded type" or is it even a "higher kinded type" (both of which I have not yet understood)? You see, I'm swimming here...

Comment: Understandable, @Dierk. When I met the concept of type expressions (i.e. application of type expressions to other type expressions) the first time I couldn't wrap my head around it easily. After all, in other PL you have *at best* a type, and that's it. Now you have like lego pieces you need to combine to get a type! But parameterized comes indeed very close. Types of kind * = types as you knew it until now. You get a more complex type k2 by applying a type expression of kind (k1 -> k2) to a type expression of kind k1 - just like you get b when you apply a function with type (a -> b) to an a.